# Would you say that being a student on careers is harmful?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I have a [CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/shaun-finglas) listed upon Careers under the Student account type.

While I am a student, I graduate in the coming months (I'll be done by this summer time) so I was wondering what the opinion was of listing my CV as a student.

Would you say it's harmful in terms that employers may simply disregard it as it is labeled as a student account, or do they not know until they view your CV?

I'm pretty hard done for when it comes to money (boo hoo) so splashing out for something that I'm getting for free seems pointless, but at the same time if it helps me get a job for when I finish university, I'm all for it.

Any advice?

Comment: Being a student is not necessarily bad. If there are two people with the same experience, skills, etc, most likely the youngest will be hired. I am a student and I have probably more experience (not necessarily work experience -- open source and hobby projects, etc) than many people who finished college, and there are many other people like me. Probably HR knows that, so they will check out your CV anyway. It may even be a plus, in some circumstances.

Comment: It cannot be much worse than the picture of you drinking an excessive amount of beer in your profile.

Comment: Ha, good point. Suppose it shows I don't spend all my time sat in front of a computer ;)

Comment: It **is** summertime somewhere. Has been for a while.

Comment: More like sauna time really. @pav

Comment: @Geoffrey/Rich: If you think that is an excessive amount of beer, then you have a really weak liver.

Comment: @Cheese: It is excessive in comparison to what I think is typical to drink at a job interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No more than actually being a student hurts your chances.  As soon as they read your CV they'll find your work experience and schooling experience anyway.

Comment: More like "schooning" experience from the profile of the asker.

Comment: @random - What do you mean by that?

Comment: Your avatar shows that you enjoy getting blotto. @fin

Answer (score 1):

I'll disagree with Pollyanna who says (at the time I'm posting this)

> No more than actually being a student hurts your chances. As soon as they read your CV they'll find your work experience and schooling experience anyway.

...but I say, but if it wasn't there they'd *have* to read your CV to find out.  If they have a lot of resumes to look at and they're looking for easy ways to weed people out, having something like "Student" catch their eye before they've read the CV is probably not a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea was that professionals (i.e., non-students) would be encouraged to pay for a membership to prove they're serious about posting their CV online.

If someone is a 10-year pro and they have "student" on their CV, that doesn't look too good.